# Django REST Framework, working with list of objects after get_queryset

Tags: django, pagination, filtering, django-rest-framework

in my `views.py` there is ViewSet:

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_class = OrderFilter
    filter_backends = (
        OrderingFilter,
        DjangoFilterBackend,
    )
    def get_queryset(self):
         ...some query...
         return products # return QuerySet object with all products in db.
```

Where and how can I manipulate with Project objects after filtering? With ability to take data from request. For example:

```
for product in products: # after pagination, filtering, etc. 
    product.price = product.price*self.request.user.discount
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time you are using a `ModelViewSet`, you will have to override the `list()` method for example. The signature is `list(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` where as you understand, you can use the request object and manipulate your data as needed.

Let me know if you need further help!

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works for me! And it gave me understanding, how views works! :)

Comment: Glad it helped you :)